# How to make a checkbox button flash?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a checkbox shown as button. I want to make it flash when it is checked. From what Ive found, i think the simplest way is to use a timer to rotate the background color of the button.

Where I am stuck is finding the back color of the checked button. Can someone tell me what the back color is changed to by default (via designer) when the button is checked? Without that I cannot get the timer to begin the oscillation.

What I have is a Mute Button. When the mute is active i want the button to flash until it is pressed again to turn the mute off.

In case I'm wrong and the back color actually does not change, what changes about the button to make it appear pressed?

code:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              instructorTimer.Enabled = true;
              }
      private void instructorTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

             // interval is 2000
           if (checkBox1.BackColor == System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control)
                    checkBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;

           else
                    checkBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
           }
```

Comment: What technology are you using? WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `SystemColors.Control` is what you are looking for.

Make sure you have the tick event hooked up.  It looks suspect:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  timer1.Tick += instructorTimer_Tick;
}
```

I would also change the color immediately, for instant feedback:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  checkBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
  timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I thought control was right, But using that I cant get it to work.. Maybe my code is bugged up

Comment: @eatumup How fast is the timer?  You might have to call a refresh on the control, too.  Also, as everyone is mentioning, try participating more by accepting and voting more with the controls on the left side of the screen.  They are your friends.

Comment: Oops, cant believe I missed that. I was thinking post it too. The interval is 2000. Shouldn't the control auto refresh every 2000 milisecs?

Comment: @eatumup Is it hooked up right?  You have timer1 as your timer, but your tick method is called instructorTimer.  In other words, it doesn't look like your timer is actually calling it's tick event.

Comment: yup. I have two timers and mixed them up. checked and it looks hooked up right, but I'm getting no response. I erased the color commands and put in a MessageBox.Show() and got nothing. Gonna look at it in more detail. I think that something else isn't linked.

Comment: @eatumup From the designer, try double-clicking on your instructorTimer, see if it opens the timer code or makes a new method.  Otherwise, it should be working.  BTW, 2000 is a pretty long time to wait for a flash.  500 looked better on my machine.

Comment: That was it. Somthing got messed up. I deleted all the old stuff and started over. It works now. You all are the best. Thanks Very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;

            Application.DoEvents();
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();

            do
            {

            }
            while (ts.Milliseconds == 2000);

            checkBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        }
```

Comment: You have asked five  questions and have only accepted one, the questions you asked would have taken up a fair bit of peoples time. Kindly do the needful and accept some of those answers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. To be honest I never really realized that I even excepted the one. I just missed the control all together. Apologies, still learning.

Comment: @eatumup - same here - when I started I didn't even notice the "holo ticks" under each answers votes. When someone told me they mentioned that you get 3 pts or so for accepting a correct answer. cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a UserControl instead of trying to repurpose Button - the following should work great and you can extend it if something doesn't work like you like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlashyButton
{
    public partial class FlashyButton : UserControl
    {
        private CheckState _Checked = CheckState.Unchecked;

        [Browsable(true)]
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
                lblText.Text = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public FlashyButton()
        {
            this.CausesValidation = true;
            InitializeComponent();
            lblText.MouseClick += (sender, e) => { OnMouseClick(null); };
        }

        public void SetFont(Font WhichFont)
        {
            this.Font = WhichFont;
        }

        public CheckState GetCheckedState()
        {
            return this._Checked;
        }

        public void SetCheckedState(CheckState NewCheckState) 
        {
            this._Checked = NewCheckState;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this._Checked = (this._Checked == CheckState.Checked) ? CheckState.Unchecked : CheckState.Checked;
            this.BorderStyle = (this._Checked == CheckState.Checked) ? System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D : System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            tmrRedraw.Enabled = (this._Checked == CheckState.Checked);
            if (this._Checked == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            }
            this.Invalidate();            //Force redraw
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
        }

        private float Percent = 100;
        private void tmrRedraw_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Percent -= 2;
            if (Percent < -100) Percent = 100;
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(
                255, 
                Lerp(255, SystemColors.Control.R, (int)Math.Abs(Percent)), 
                Lerp(0, SystemColors.Control.G, (int)Math.Abs(Percent)), 
                Lerp(0, SystemColors.Control.B, (int)Math.Abs(Percent))
                );
        }

        private int Lerp(int Start, int End, int Percent)
        {
            return ((int) ((float)(End - Start) * ((float)Percent / 100f)) + Start);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the .Designer code as well (just replace what you already have when you make a new control by this name)

```
namespace FlashyButton
{
    partial class FlashyButton
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.lblText = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.tmrRedraw = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // lblText
            // 
            this.lblText.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblText.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
            this.lblText.Name = "lblText";
            this.lblText.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 17);
            this.lblText.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblText.Text = "Sample";
            // 
            // tmrRedraw
            // 
            this.tmrRedraw.Interval = 10;
            this.tmrRedraw.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.tmrRedraw_Tick);
            // 
            // FlashyButton
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblText);
            this.Name = "FlashyButton";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(148, 148);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblText;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrRedraw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I had a CheckBox with Appearance = Button and FlatStyle = Flat and wanted it flashing when checked:

```
private void timer_Flashing_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox_Refresh.Checked)
        {
            if (checkBox_Refresh.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                checkBox_Refresh.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox_Refresh.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```